# Handle Next And Previous Button in MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

### This is how I am doing this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.next: {
            currentFile = input.get(currentPosition + 1);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            try{
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentFile);
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
        case R.id.prev: {

            currentFile = input.get(currentPosition - 1);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentFile);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

### }

Can't play the next and previous buttons. I want to play next and previous track from raw folder. I tried to do so but I am unable to do this. Give some suggestions. Thank You...

Comment: You are playing the same song when you click next and previous

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: unable to find DataSource....